# How can I truncate a String before and after a specific keyword?

Tags: php

I have a string and I want to search a keyword and the string should truncated before and after the keyword.

Example:

`…erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et FOO BAR et justo duo dolores et ea reb…`

If the keyword is at the beginning, the text should be not truncated.

`At vero eos et FOO BAR et justo duo dolores et ea reb, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…`

Here is my snippet. It's not really good...

```php
$keyword = 'FOO BAR';
$truncateChar = '…';
$truncateCharLength = mb_strlen($truncateChar);
$truncateLength = 80;
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et FOO BAR et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';

// Find the position of the keyword
$position = mb_strpos($str, $keyword);

if (($position - ($truncateLength / 2)) < 0) {
    // if there are not enough  chars ($truncateLength/2) before the keyword,
    // don't truncate at the beginning.
    $str = mb_substr($str, 0);
} else {
    // truncate ($truncateLength/2) chars before the keyword
    $str = $truncateChar . mb_substr($str, $position - ($truncateLength / 2));
}

// if the string is longer than $truncateLength, than truncate the string
if (mb_strlen($str) > $truncateLength) {
    $str = mb_substr($str, 0, $truncateLength - $truncateCharLength) . $truncateChar;
}

echo $str;
```

It's for a search result. I don't want to display the whole text. Only the part where the keyword is displayed. Is there a better performance way to do that? Regex e.g.?

Comment: Your example is difficult to understand. Maybe give a explicit keyword or something

Comment: Well, the code works. What is the problem with it? I don't think you can't get any better throwing some regexp to it.

Comment: @Amarnasan - I think his issue is that the result has not the given length of 80 characters.

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance, something like this might do the trick.. Haven't tested, just on top of my head, so you can give it a try.. Maybe modify it a bit to satisfy your request because it might run into trouble when the word in question is found multiple times.. Idk, it might help you to start:

```
    preg_match('/.{0,40}FOO BAR.{0,40}/im', 'At vero eos et FOO BAR justo duo dolores et ea reb, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', $match);
    echo $match ? '...' . reset($match) . '...' : '';
```

Comment: "*If the keyword is at the beginning, the text should be not truncated.*"

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.. My impression was that he wants to keep characters on the left if there are enough of them, and if there are more, to truncate on the left too..?

Answer (score 0):

This code will try to return an 80 chars substring with the searched characters as much centered as possible.

```
<?php
$keyword = 'FOO BAR';
$truncateChar = '…';
$truncateCharLength = mb_strlen($truncateChar);
$truncateLength = 80;
$tests = [
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 FOO BAR 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   'FOO BAR 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 FOO BAR 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 FOO BAR 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 FOO BAR  23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 FOO BAR 35 36 37 38 39 40',
   '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 FOO BAR 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54',
   ];
   $str = "";
   foreach($tests as $orig_str) {
       if ($position = mb_strpos($orig_str, $keyword) !== FALSE) {
           $position = mb_strpos($orig_str, $keyword);
           $start = max($position - ($truncateLength - strlen($keyword))/2,0);
           $str = substr($orig_str, $start, $truncateLength);
           $str = strlen($str)==$truncateLength?$str:substr($orig_str, max(strlen($orig_str)-$truncateLength,0),$truncateLength);
           if (mb_strpos($orig_str, $keyword)!= mb_strpos($str, $keyword)) $str = $truncateChar.$str;
       }
       echo $str, " ",  "\n";
   }
```

will return

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 FOO BAR 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 2 
FOO BAR 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 2 
0 1 2 3 4 FOO BAR 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 2 
0 1 2 3 4 FOO BAR 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 2 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 FOO BAR 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 FOO BAR  23 2 
… 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 FOO BAR 35 36 37 38 39 40 
… 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 FOO BAR 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
```

Comment: Missing `…` at the end of the 5 first tests and the last one.